# Почему я не могу обратиться к полю обьекта. который получил из ApplicationContext?

Tags: java, spring

Разбираюсь со Spring-ом, и столкнулся с непонятной для меня ситуацией.
Создал

```
abstract public class Animal {
String name;
}

@Component
public class Dog extends Animal{
    public String name;
    public Dog() {}
    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return "Im a Dog";
    }
}

@Component
public class Cat extends Animal {
    public String name;
    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }
    public void setName(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }
    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return "Im a Cat";
    }
}

public class Application {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
    ApplicationContext appContext = new AnnotationConfigApplicationContext(AppConfig.class);
      Animal dogBean = appContext.getBean(Dog.class);
      Animal catBean = appContext.getBean(Cat.class);

      System.out.println(dogBean);//провека
      System.out.println(catBean);
      
      catBean. (и вот тут я не имею доступа к полю "name" и public пробовал и set и get)
      dogBean. (пробовал и с пустым конструктором никак не могу обратиться к полю. а метод toString вполне работает и выводит)
    }
}
```

Подскажите пожалуйста а как мне работать с состоянием объекта, если я получаю его из контекста?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Spring тут не при чём.
Класс Animal не содержит доступного поля name.
А переменные dogBean и catBean объявлены как Animal.
Поэтому компилятор и IDE не позволяют обращения к полю name, не смотря на то, что в процессе выполнения они будут указывать на объекты, имеющие такие поля.